# (eval):1: command not found: "export

Tags: terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh, zshrc

[Error on startup on terminal/iterm2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4IsM.png)
First post on stack overflow.

I keep getting this error. I've looked around the web for a fix but to no avail.

I suspect it's something related to my .zshrc file.
My suspicion arises because for the past two days I've gone on the journey of customizing my terminal by downloading many things (oh-my-zsh, powerlevel10k, to name a few).

AFAIK the functionality of my terminal/iterm2 seems to be working fine. But this error message is getting to me.

Thank you.

[Beginning snippet of my .zshrc file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQbca.png)

I looked into my .zshrc, .zprofile files and looked at lines which began with 'export'. Apparently the word 'export' is a built-in zsh, so there shouldn't be a reason for the command to not be found, right?

Comment: Can you post more of your .zshrc? Are you sure you don't have any lines beginning with `“export`? Try `grep "^.export" .zshrc`. Those also don't look like normal quote characters, the screenshot contains `“` and `”` instead of `"`.

Comment: PS: It's better to post the zshrc as text rather than as an image. Text is easier to copy/paste, and works better with screen readers.

Comment: According to the screenshot, `eval` does not complain about a command named `export`. It complains about a command named `"export`. Please show the offending line in your startup files which cause the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like you used the wrong kind of double quotes. You must use ASCII double quotes `"` (code decimal 34), not some "curly" double quotes found in Unicode and outside the ASCII range. This usually happens when cutting & pasting from Word documents or other applications that automatically change double quotes to curly double quotes for aesthetic/typography reasons.

Comment: Hi Jens. Thanks to your comment and the one from @Alira, I began my search through my .zshrc file for any curly quotes around any 'export' key words. To my surprise, I did find particular double quotes that were different from all the others, but there were on a complete different line of code I wouldn't have expected:

eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"

I fixed it, restarted terminal and voila, no more error message. You were spot on Jens, I must have copied this code from somewhere else along with the curly double quote. 

Thank you very much!